# Nativescript - Update viewModel from an imported function

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to create a common functions file in NS8 app. One of the function has to do some http requests and then update the viewModel to show the loaded data. I'm not able to achieve this when the function is placed in a separate file. Here's basically what I have right now.

main.js

```
import { ApplicationSettings, Http, fromObject } from '@nativescript/core';
import * as commFunc from '../functions.js';

var page,
  viewMode = new fromObject({
    foo: 'bar'
  });

export function onLoaded(args){
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    commFunc.getPosition();
}
```

functions.js

```
import { ApplicationSettings, Http, Observable } from '@nativescript/core';
var viewModel = new Observable();

export function getPosition(){
  // beep boop bap calculating
  viewModel.foo = 'baz';
}
```

I also tried passing the `viewModel` as a parameter but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way to do this is have getPosition return a value, and the caller assign the value into the viewModel, such as

```
viewModel.set("foo",commFunc.getPosition());
```

That said, I have functions that pass viewModel as a parameter.  You'd need to remove the local declaration in function.js, though.

Comment: Ah, removing that declaration made it work. Thanks a lot. Please put that as your answer as it is what I wanted to do.